# CSS grid, remove gap when area is optional

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

I'm starting using CSS grid (pretty amazing!). I'm starting with the most basic layout: mobile layout. Also, I'm using media queries to change the layout as the web page grows.

For now, my layout consists of 3 areas. The exact order is the content area, the sidebar area and the commenting area. The **commenting area is optional** and may not display at all. There is a **gap of 40px** between areas.

This is the mobile layout css

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 40px;
}
```

If the commenting area doesn't exist, the gap for the commenting area also does not exist, which it's what i want.

https://jsfiddle.net/p54od8ho/

When the page grows, i'm changing the layout, like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .content {
    grid-area: content;
  }
  .sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar;
  }
  .comments {
    grid-area: comment;
  }
  .grid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-template-areas:
            "content sidebar"
            "comment sidebar";
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g20gtd4z/

The gap of 40px exists because the comment area exists.

But, this is what happens when the comment area does not exist:

https://jsfiddle.net/6Lfg55my/1/

If you notice, even if the comment area doesn't exist, the 40px gap exists.

I believe one solution is to create a class, just to remove the comment area.

```
.grid.no_comment {
            grid-template-areas:
                "content sidebar"
                ". sidebar";
      }
```

There has to be a better and more simple way (or maybe not)..
Is there a way, using only the grid options, to make it so when the comment area does not exist, the gap is also gone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the comment area exists, you have two columns and two rows in the container:

```
.grid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-gap: 40px;
        grid-template-areas:
            "content sidebar"
            "comment sidebar";
  }
```

So, naturally, `grid-gap` applies between the first and second row (and column).

When the comment area is removed, *there are still two columns and two rows in the container*. Removing that item doesn't change the value of `grid-template-areas`.

So, naturally, `grid-gap` continues to apply between the two rows. Except now, with the comment section gone, there's a bigger space in that grid area.

When you want the comment section removed, instead of removing that grid item, why not remove the entire second row? `grip-gap` only works *between* grid items.

```
.grid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-gap: 40px;
        grid-template-areas:
            "content sidebar"
            /* "comment sidebar" */
            ;
  }
```

Comment: For complicated layouts, this solution is cumbersome at best. Seems there must be a way to handle this on the fly without having to re-define the entire grid-template-areas.

Comment: @Dave - I would expect an extra `grid` property which toggles the ability to *ignore* named `grid-area` elements that aren't rendered, instead of dedicating an empty space, without checking if the element actually exists (in the DOM). That would be a game-changer for grid-based designs

Comment: @Dave Yup, I agree. For application layout CSS is still pretty much crap. What we need is something like <http://tech.dolhub.com/code/MatrixLayout>.